# SonarQube extension versions 3.x compatible with Tfs2018 on prem

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We currently make use of the Tfs SonarQube extension (version 3.1.0) on an onprem Tfs2015.Update3 (14.102.25423.0)
We use the following sonar tasks in our build definitions:

- Prepare the SonarQube analysis
- Complete the SonarQube analysis

These all work fine.

I have now upgraded the Tfs server to Tfs2018 (version 16.122.27102.1).
To my (pleasant:- ) surprise the SonarQube extension (version 3.1.0) still works!

When I however read this link on the sonarqube site, it seems like versions 3.x should NOT be compatible with Tfs 2018.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS

> Versions 3.x are compatible with:
>
> - TFS 2015 Update 3
> - TFS 2017 Update 1
> - VSTS
>
> Versions 4.x are compatible with:
>
> - TFS 2017 Update 2+
> - TFS 2018
> - VSTS

Am I missing something here?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you not want to use V4.x?

Comment: That was indeed my thinking as well. Unfortunately as soon as it was discovered that V3.x works with Tfs2018, my upgrade suggestion to V4.x pretty quickly ran out of steam with the powers that be. I am therefore trying to figure out what the reason is for this unexpected compatibility and if there are any risks in leaving it as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compatibility "matrix" on the [VSTS/TFS documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS) gives the recommended setup - i.e. what has been tested and will work for sure.

In other words, versions 3.X might be forward compatible with recent versions of TFS - but this compatibility is not tested and will probably (even certainly) be broken some day in the future.

This is why this is a very good suggestion to move to the recommended versions (here 4.x for a TS 2018+) so that:

- your setup does not get broken without notice when upgrading your TFS
- you benefit from all the latest new features and improvements that won't be backported to the 3.x versions.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice, much appreciated!